# Is Node.js backwards compatible?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My belief is that Node.js is backwards compatible. A script that runs in Node.js N should also run in Node.js N+1. Is there any documentation that I couldn't find mentioning this? Or is there some way of knowing other than simply installing a newer version and test it?

I've written some scripts a few years ago, back when the current Node.js major release was v5. I want to upgrade the system, but need to be sure that the current process will not break.

Comment: *Javascript* will probably always be *backwards* compatible, since they won't break anything on the web. Node-specific APIs *may* someday change. There's no such thing as "forward compatibility", only backwards compatible interpreters and APIs.

Comment: @deceze There are ways of designing an API/protocol so that it is impossible to extend it while preserving backwards-compatibility. Those would be called "not forward-compatible".

Comment: "Forward compatible" would mean "Is today's Node.js compatible with future versions and features of Javascript?", and the answer would necessarily be no.

Comment: Node major releases have definitely deprecated and removed functions and modules (or methods within modules).  The ABI has changed significantly several times (in earlier versions especially) as well.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that what you are looking for is [this website](https://node.green/).